# Ruby require - cannot load such file - my own gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've pushed gem into rubygems. I can install it, but I can't require it.

> irb(main):032:0> require 'jsql'
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     4: from C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
>     3: from (irb):32
>     2: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
>     1: from C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:122:in `require'
> ```
>
> LoadError (cannot load such file -- jsql)

I've had this problem once, with mechanize gem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've create a gem called `jsql` which is listed on https://rubygems.org/gems/jsql.

So in orer to use it, you need to install it, either with `gem install jsql` or add it to the Gemfile of you project, along with other dependencies, and run `bundle install`

Only after this procedures, your gem will be available for use.

Comment: I've installed it. I know how to use gems. Problem is solved. I've made mistake with name. Gem is called jsql, but rb file was named jsql_beta. After I've changed it, requre almost wors. Still have another problem.

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs when the gem isn't installed for the ruby version you're using.

It happened to me with the `irb` gem, so I ran

```sh
RBENV_VERSION=2.6.3 gem install irb
```

I found that helpful note [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/1166#issuecomment-494449336). But the same could apply for any gem, just check the ruby version with `ruby --version` and try the above code (replacing irb with whatever gem you want to install)